# linux makefile linking error __line__

Tags: linux, unix

I am getting the following error in Linux "undefined reference to `__line__`.  I know that C has implicit macro `__LINE__`.  In code `__line__` is assigned with `__LINE__` as

```
extern int __line__;
LDF(__line__ = __LINE__);
```

so `__line__` is a variable not macro here which is assigned with value of `__LINE__`.  Here it is `extern int`,  so it should have been declared somewhere as just `int __line__`.  But am not seeing any header or c file where _*line*_is declared.  Also this error am getting not during compilation of .c file but while linking of .o files.

This error is not coming in UNIX.  Additionally while linking libgen, libposix4 libraries are linked.  These libraries are present only in UNIX not in LINUX I assume that `int __line__;` is present somewhere in these libraries or how can i resolve this error?

Comment: Mybe you meant `__LINE__` ? (oops cms typo) `__LINE__` is an automagic macro, which to the C-compiler still is a constant (but with a defferent substitution for every line) @OP: backticks do the magic.

Comment: The revision history will show you how I formatted your post. Click on the time stamp where it says "edited ..." above my gravitar.

Comment: thank you .. i was trying to edit and couldnt..

Comment: LDF is a just a function. no worry about that.. my question is inside file "extern int __line__" so somewhere "int __line__ " should be there.  so how its working in UNIX but not in LINUX.  only difference during  linking is, libgen, libposix libraries are linked which are present in UNIX but not available in LINUX

Comment: Dont start identifiers with double underscores. They are reserved for the implementation. (also underscores are *sometimes* stripped by the linker, depending on the phase of the moon.)

Comment: Its not the code I wrote.It is existing code and am just porting from unix to linux.  why its not throwing error undefined reference to" in unix?

Answer (score 1):

@rodrigo @sehe. thanks for your inputs.  I found the line int **line**=0; in one of ".c" file and that object of that file is created and along with some more object files archieve file  ".a" library file is created.  That is, common.c has int **line**= 0; and common.o and some x.o, y.o are archieved to create "libcommon.a" using command "ar ruv" and this library is linked to create binary executable as -lcommon in makefile.  again thanks for your inputs!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`__line__` is unfortunately prohibited as a portable identifier by the standard(s).

The fact that it 'worked' on UNIX, is implementation defined, and you are witnessing the fact that isn't portable.

My only advice is to rename that variable. You *could* play with fire and add something really evil to the compilation flags:

```
-D__line__=MYCODEBASE_LINE__
```

but I don't particularly recommend such a thing

Comment: thanks for your answers !!! i understood why it is there in code. its just to print line no which can be achieved with C macro __LINE__ itself. But if i pass to compiler with the option -D__line__=__LINE__ it means am defining a macro. but in code it is declared as integer variable. So better I rename or remove from code as for the function its passed as LDF(__line__ = __LINE__) . Instead I will use LDF(__LINE__).

Comment: @smileybhuff A macro doesn't exist to the linker. The macro makes the compiler see a different word in fact. As long as your definition of `__line__` in some other translation  unit gets preprocessed with the same '#define' it should work. (Of course, I'm assuming, `__line__` is defined _in your program_)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a non-standard, undocumented, internal variable that happens to be in some of the libraries used.

And some clever guy found some use for it in your program. You should try to understand why is there and whether it is really needed, because chances are that it simply does not exist in Linux.

That's why it starts with the double underscore: because that name is *reserved*.

Comment: thanks for your answers !!! i understood why it is there in code.  its just to print line no which can be achieved with C macro __LINE__ itself.  But if i pass to compiler with the option -D__line__=__LINE__ it means am defining a macro.  but in code it is declared as integer variable.  So better I rename or remove from code as for the function its passed as LDF(__line__ = __LINE__) .  Instead I will use LDF(__LINE__).

Comment: @rodrigo: I wouldn't be surprised if `__line__` is global a variable defined in a translation unit related to logging (?)

Comment: @smileybhuff - My point exactly, if you don't need `__line__` and it does not exist, just delete it!